# Rotation matrix and unitary similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, change-of-basis, unitary-matrices

Let
$$
\text{U}(\theta;i,j)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
& \ddots \\
&& 1 \\
&&&\cos\theta&&&&-\sin\theta \\
&&&&1 \\
&&&&&\ddots \\
&&&&&&1 \\
&&&\sin\theta&&&&\cos\theta \\
&&&&&&&&1 \\
&&&&&&&&&\ddots \\
&&&&&&&&&&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
the rotation matrix on coordinates i,j plane.

How to explain why only rows and columns of indexes i and j are changed in a unitary equivalence like :
$$
A = U(\theta;i,j)BU^*(\theta;i,j),\hspace{16pt}A,B \in M_n
$$
It seem pretty obvious but I can't put words on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful tool here is the following fact if $e_1,\dots,e_n \in \Bbb R^n$ denote the standard basis vectors, then the $i,j$ entry of $A$ is given by $A_{ij} = e_i^*A e_j$. With that, note that for any $k \notin \{i,j\}$, the matrix $U = U(\theta; i,j)$ satisfies $U^*e_k = e_k$. It follows that for any $p,q$ (both not equal to $i$ or $j$), we have
$$
A_{ij} =  e_i^T[UBU^*]e_j = [U^*e_i]^* B [U^*e_j] = e_i^* B e_j = B_{ij}.
$$